# Instruction in for loop only executes once?

Tags: c, loops

I have a for loop in my program. It looks just like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        n = i*2;
        if(n >= 50)
            n-=50;

        printf("n is %d\n", n); 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

The plan was just to have n reset to 0 after it reaches 50. That's all, however when I print this out, n only gets reset one time. What gives?

Comment: Do the math in your head with `i` equal to 51. What will `n` be after the first line in the loop? Will it pass the `if` condition? What's its value after that?

Answer (score 7):

Draw a table and you'll know why:

```
  i  |  n
-----+------
  0  |  0     n >= 50 ? No
  1  |  2     n >= 50 ? No
  2  |  4
  3  |  6
 ... | ...
  25 | 50     n >= 50 ? YES!
  25 |  0     n-=50
  26 | 52     n >= 50 ? YES!
  26 |  2     n-=50  → n will be 2 and NOT 0
```

What to do?

Simply reset it to **0** instead of removing 50 from it or `n-= i*2` (Which is funny to write because `i*2` is `n`, so simply do `n = 0`)

*Tip*: Drawing a table is easy, but using a debugger is ten times easier. Use it.

---

<strike>**EDIT**: (If I'm really understanding what you mean..)</strike>

Regarding your comment, you have to change the condition to:

```
if(n % 50 == 0)
     n = 0;
```

Comment: That's it `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`!!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan LOL.. you still remember this

Comment: Yes :) , Adding [**this working code**](http://codepad.org/mqtaq7O6) that shows, executes each times after `i >= 25` check

Comment: I changed the line from n -= 50 to n = 0. I get a similar error. N is now always 0 after that executes now.

Grijesh, in your working code example, lines 77 and onward are the problem. Notice how n is only reset one time there?

Comment: "*The plan was just to have n reset to 0 after it reaches 50*" - This is what I understood from your question. If you want to reset it only one time, use a flag to indicate when you've done this.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry, I mean every time it reaches 50.

Comment: Yet when n is printed (see Grijesh's working code example), n reaches upwards of 100. It only goes back to 0 one time, not every time it reaches 50.

Answer (score 1):

If the plan is to have n reset to 0 after it reaches 50, then reset it to 0 instead of subtracting 50:

```
if(n >= 50)
    n = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 if(n >= 50)
      n = 0;
```

to reset `n` to `0` after it reaches `50`.

Comment: Yup, that's much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are just subtracting 50 from the current value of n. Consider this:

```
When i = 25 your condition will reset n to 0
When i = 26 your condition will reset n to 2
When i = 27 your condition will reset n to 4
When i = 28 your condition will reset n to 6
and so on...
```

You can just assign 0 to n instead of subtracting 50.

**OR**

You can replace

```
if(n >= 50)
    n-=50;

printf("n is %d\n", n);
```

with just

```
printf("n is %d\n", (n >= 50)?0:n);
```